# Protobuf toolchain/plugin for C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

In my company we already have a Java project (build by Maven) that is compiling proto files into Java via `maven-protoc-plugin`. Right now we are trying to do the same for C# (MSbuild + NuGet).

My problem is that I cannot find any toolchain for MSbuild that will compile proto into C# classes. I already have installed `Google Protobuf for .NET 4.0` via NuGet.

I want to use protobuf 2 with VisualStudio 2013

PS
My main programming language is Java and I really suck at C# so please speak to me really slow ;).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the recommendation of [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net)
The tool for creating classes out of .proto file is called protogen.

> protogen -i:test2.proto -o:test2.cs

Typically one would define Pre-Build Build Event in VS which will trigger the recreation of the classes before the actual compilation.

Comment: I went into Project -> Properties -> Pre build event command, then added command *protogen -i:... -o:...*, but when I build project I get error (exited with code 1).

Comment: How did you install Protobuf-net - Nuget? I guess you will need to use relativ pathcs inside the pre build event

Comment: Before adding the event you should try it with the command line.

Comment: Where can I start command line that is bootstraped in my project? Or should I just run *cmd*?

Comment: I usually just use cmd and go to the root directory of the solution.

Comment: I installed protobuf-net by *Install-Package protobuf-net*. Now when I'm trying to run *protogen* from main folder of my app I get *'protogen' is not recognized as...*. Should I go in some folder to run it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110504/discussion-between-weismat-and-magx2).

Answer (score 0):

You want [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net)! It'll do everything you need!

Seriously though, it'll allow you to avoid using .proto files if you want by marking a class/property with attributes. However, it also comes with a pre-compiler to process your existing .proto files into C# classes. We use it on a large-scale project and it works really well.

Comment: But I want to use .proto files (they are still used in Java and Java app stays). 

Second thing how can I compile proto ->C# with this protobuf-net?

Comment: @MAGx2 At the bottom of the link there's a section about using the pre-compiler.